# Tree list recursion from Stanford tutorial

Tags: c++, tree, linked-list

I have found this appearing-to-be famous problem in Stanford tutorial about trees and decided to solve it.

My solution appears to work great:

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct num {

        int n;
        num* left;
        num* right;
        num* next;
        num* pre;
    };

    num* cr (int data) {

        num* node = new num;
        node->n = data;
        node->left = 0;
        node->right = 0;
        return node;
    }

/* function for tree creation*/
    void treecre (num* & node) {

        node = cr (10);
        node->left = cr (8);
        node->left->left = cr (6);
        node->left->left->left = cr (4);
        node->right = cr (12);
        node->right->right = cr (14);
        node->right->right->right = cr (16);
        node->right->left = cr(11);
        node ->left->right = cr (9);
    }
   // function for transforming the tree into linked list with next and previous // links 
// but without linking the first and last element yet
    num* btc (num* node, num*& list) {
        num* temp1 = 0;
        num* max = node;
        if (node == 0) return 0;
        else {
        btc (node->right, list);
        num* temp = new num;
        temp->n = node->n;
        temp ->next = list;
        if (list != 0) list->pre = temp;
        list = temp;
        btc (node->left, list);
        }
        return list;
    }

    void printtree (num* node) {
        if (node != 0) {
            printtree (node->left);
            cout << node->n;
            printtree (node->right);
        }
    }
    // printing the linked list backwards
    void printback (num*& list, int& k) {
        if (k < 15) {
            cout << list->n;
            list = list->pre;
            printback (list, ++k);}
        else {cout << list->n;}
    }
    // and in right direction
    void printlistto (num*& list, int& k) {
        if (k < 12) {
            cout << list->n;
            list = list->next;
            printlistto (list, ++k);
        }
        else {
            cout << list->n; }
    }


    int main () {
        num* node = 0;
        num* list = 0;
        int k = 0;
        treecre (node);
        printtree (node);
        cout << endl;
        list = btc (node, list);
// next lines link the first and last elemets
        num* temp1 = list;
        if (temp1->next!= 0) {
        while (temp1->next != 0) {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }}
        temp1->next = list;
        list->pre = temp1;

        printback (list, k);
        cout << endl;
        cin.get ();
        cin.ignore();
    }
```

But then I take a look at [this Stanford solution](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/109/TreeListRecursion.html#challenge), which is way longer and uses other tactics.

Could you please tell me if I overlooked something? Does my version have some sufficient drawbacks or if it is fine?

Comment: Should really be re-classified as C. May use some C++ features but the style is definitely not C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution may work great, but I see some room for improvement, especially in terms of readability and maintainability and using OO.

I quickly went over your recursive function btc, it seems to do the trick. But the code is a bit messy.

The stanford solution tries to embrace the typical list methods, like: appending elements, joining lists, etc. In fact that's the goal, right: porting a binary sorted tree to a list, so one should also provide a good list interface. They also do this in a good object oriented/modular and readable way.

**A review on your coding style**

To start: you miss some indentation (in your if/else clauses). This already can make it more readable!
Perhaps also document some steps in the recursion method, since recursion always results to confusion.

---

**Methods**

your method names are not that understandable, use camelCase and use appropriate, complete names, that indicate the purpose of the method.

for example:

```
treecre()
```

should be

```
treeCreate()
```

it would even be better to use a Tree class that has a `create()` method, which builds your test tree.

---

**Classes**

You also used a struct for your node, may I suggest to use classes, since they offer a wide set of feature that can be used for future purposes of your code: inheritance, polymorphism, etc. This is important since one might want to extend this implementation to handle nodes that contain ASCII characters instead of integers.  Or, refactor the class to use C++ templates to support generic types.

In addition I would use the standard list/binary tree names, like: root, node, .. which is easier for communication purposes.

I hope this is a bit helpful!